# What is the idiomatic way to return either a struct or an error?

Tags: error-handling, go, zero

I have a function that returns either a `Card`, which is a `struct` type, or an error.

The problem is, how can I return from the function when an error occurs ? `nil` is not valid for structs and I don't have a valid zero value for my `Card` type.

```
func canFail() (card Card, err error) {
    // return nil, errors.New("Not yet implemented"); // Fails
    return Card{Ace, Spades}, errors.New("not yet implemented"); // Works, but very ugly
}
```

The only workaround I found is to use a `*Card` rather than a `Card`, a make it either `nil` when there is an error or make it point an actual `Card` when no error happens, but that's quite clumsy.

```
func canFail() (card *Card, err error) {
    return nil, errors.New("not yet implemented");
}
```

Is there a better way ?

EDIT : I found another way, but don't know if this is idiomatic or even good style.

```
func canFail() (card Card, err error) {
    return card, errors.New("not yet implemented")
}
```

Since `card` is a named return value, I can use it without initializing it. It is zeroed in its own way, I don't really care since the calling function is not supposed to use this value.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
func canFail() (card Card, err error) {
    return card, errors.New("not yet implemented")
}
```

I think this, your third exampe, is fine too.  The understood rule is that when a function returns an error, other return values cannot be relied upon to have meaningful values unless documentation clearly explains otherwise.  So returning a perhaps meaningless struct value here is fine.

Comment: It's pretty idiomatic to return a pointer so you can use nil. It helps to avoid mistakes and makes early returns easier to do when you aren't using named return values.

Comment: While it's certainly handy to be able to return nil instead of a pointer, I wouldn't use pointers for that reason alone. The fact that a non-nil error was returned is sufficient to tell you not to use the data in 'card'. You should be checking the error rather than the value. Otherwise there's little point in returning an error at all...

Answer (score 8):

For example,

```
type Card struct {
}

func canFail() (card Card, err error) {
    return Card{}, errors.New("not yet implemented")
}
```

Comment: In this example the return values don't even have to be named.  (You might still want them named for other reasons, or you might feel the function is clearer without the clutter of names.)

Comment: Read the question and my answer. This is a stub function to be implemented later--empty `struct` and `"not yet implemented"` message. Since we have no idea what code will be used to implement the function, the only safe way is to return well defined values whatever code is used later.

Answer (score 3):

```
func canFail() (card Card, err error) {
        if somethingWrong {
                err = errors.New("Not yet implemented")
                return
        }

        if foo {
                card = baz
                return
        }

        ... 

        // or 
        return Card{Ace, Spades}, nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so that's semantically close to my last solution, although a little different regarding syntax

Answer (score 1):

For me, I prefer your second option.

```
func canFail() (card *Card, err error) {
    return nil, errors.New("not yet implemented");
}
```

This way you can make sure that when errors happen, the `canFail()` callers won't be able to use the `card` since it's nil. We can't make sure that the callers will check the error first.

Answer (score 1):

peterSO's answer is the closest, but it's not quite what I would use. I think this is best:

```
func canFail() (Card, error) {
   return Card{}, errors.New("not yet implemented")
}
```

First, it's not using a pointer just so it can use `nil` for returns. I think that's a neat trick, but unless you actually need the `struct` to be a pointer (for modifying or other reason), then returning a value is better. Also I don't think the return values should be named, unless you are utilizing them, like this:

```
func canFail() (card Card, err error) {
   return
}
```

and that is problematic for two reasons. First, you aren't always going to be in a situation where you can simply have the return value be whatever that variable is at the time. Second, if you have a larger function, you won't be able to use a naked return in the deeper levels, as you will get variable shadow errors.

Finally, using `Card{}` instead of `nil` or `card` is more verbose, but it better communicates what you are doing. If you use either of these:

```
return
return card, err
```

It's not clear without context if the function was successful or not, while this:

```
return Card{}, err
```

is pretty clear that the function failed. It's the same pattern you would use with primitive types:

```
return false, err
return 0, err
return '\x00', err
return "", err
return []byte{}, err
```

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#pass-values

Answer (score 0):

As a possible alternative to returning the struct you might consider letting the caller allocate it and the function set params.

```
func canFail(card *Card) (err error) {
    if someCondition {
        // set one property
        card.Suit = Diamond

        // set all at once
        *card = Card{Ace, Spade}
    } else {
        err = errors.New("something went wrong")
    }

    return
}
```

If you are not comfortable pretending that Go supports C++ style references you should also check `card` for being `nil`.

https://play.golang.org/p/o-2TYwWCTL

Comment: consider early returns https://play.golang.org/p/fXG7H5OG6eH

Answer (score 0):

If your function does not behave like someone else would assume reading at its signature, IE, `if an error has occurred I should ignore the value along it`.

Pretty much like any [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader), which may return `n>0` with an `error`

Then, you should simply document it to explain to the user what should be  considered regarding the returned value along the error.

Changing the signature, thus the general API relationships, for such case, rare but not unavoidable, is not the way to Go.

Instead, you should adequatly document the behavior of the function.